# OBD2 Get the total mileage

Tags: android

Using mode1 31 will only give the data from Distance traveled since codes cleared. Now I have a working RPM, Vehicle Speed, Mile per trip and etc. 
Now my problem is how to get the total mileage of a car. Also, I can't find a Pid on OBD2 wiki page for total mileage.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this via the official, SAE-sanctioned, PIDs. There may be vendor-specific PIDs which support that, but they are not portable.

Comment: Thank you so much..  I found an alternative solution by saving the data when the car starts and deduct it to the current data when the car stops.